# In mongoDB, how to work with two collection from different databases and query conditions?

Tags: database, mongodb, if-statement, mongodb-query, conditional-statements

I have one collection in database **DB1** and another one is in database **DB2**.

There is a collection **"a"** in database DB1 and collection **"b"** in database DB2.

**collection a:**

Data: [image]

**collection b:**

Data: [image]

I want to filter rows in collection "a" based on **"user_id"** column in collection "b".
And I need output like this, [image]

After that, I want information like,
How many Jhon are there in data and among all Jhon, how many from USA?

Common Condition would be like,

1. select count(*), name from TABLE_NAME where name='Jhon'
2. select count(*), name from TABLE_NAME where name='Jhon' and country='USA'

So, what could be the mongoDB query to get information like this?

Comment: Please don't paste images, use formatted text see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: You could do what you want using the aggregation framework if your collections where in the SAME database. If you have multiple databases there is no way to do it, you should query your db1, extrac the info that you need for your query in db2.